# Manga where the main character is sent to be a lord of a poor area as punishment but turns it around with plant magic

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga

I can remember he gains allies and citizens of all races like cat people and dryads to help with the harvest. He makes houses out of giant trees using his magic and I believe he finds an elf hero in one of the trees who is a legend and believed to be dead.

Im sure he increases the economy by growing berries that are needed for creating healing potions and they are supposed to be really rare but he can make them in abundance. I also cant remember if his dad is the king and thinks hes useless or if he has knowledge from a past life, sorry if i am all over the place i can only remember bits and bobs of the story.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read it?  Do you remember anything distinctive about the appearance of any of the characters or the art?

Comment: Hi, thank you, I read it at the start of the year, sorry I cant remember where but in terms of style that sticks out I remember the cat race in it wasnt the usual human appearance with cat ears and tail they were basically cats that would walk like humans and speak.

Comment: Thanks FuzzyBoots I got the answer I was looking for and did the checkmark and up vote after my reputation went above 15, you have all been great, helpful and very welcoming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could this be [*Shokubutsu Mahou Cheat de Nonbiri Ryoushu Seikatsu Hajimemasu*](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/shokubutsu-mahou-cheat-de-nonbiri-ryoushu-seikatsu-hajimemasu)?

[image: Front cover of Shokubutsu Mahou Cheat de Nonbiri Ryoushu Seikatsu Hajimemasu]

> Elt, who reincarnated in an MMORPG as an aristocrat, was branded as incompetent and was thrown out as a manager of a remote area with zero territories. However, his "plant magic" was the best all-purpose magic for territorial development! As he cultivated by utilizing the magic that produces from crops to buildings and the knowledge of the previous life, the territory increased and became lively.

Keywords searched for were `manga poor lord "plant magic"`

Comment: this is the one! thank you very much it was really annoying me!